# Mesh will not move with the rig

Tags: mesh, armature

I have been attempting to work on a custom Quake Live Player Model, but alas, the skeleton and the mesh generally do not co-operate. This is my second go at the project and it seems only the head works. The rig and model have been parented with automatic weight painting. Most of the mesh appears has been weight painted.

Currently I have tried resizing the model which doesn't seem to have helped with the automatic weight process. As of now the only way I have been somewhat capable of getting the legs to move is if I pair the rig a second time with automatic weights, and even that has some caveats. Once I completed the second pairing I decided to remove the previous attempt. But the mesh will only move with two armatures. Even then the movement is simply terrible even with reattempting the weight painting process. I am genuinely at a loss and am unsure about what I am over looking.

Currently only the head works, and the legs have been weight painted and house an armature.

*Edit

https://blend-exchange.com/b/pmw3o8QK

Comment: there are things, which can be described by words like paintings, but you can write 10 books about it and despite it - one image of it will say more. Same is true for for more complicated things like rigging. So i would recommend you provide your blend file so we can check it out, because you didn't provide any technical setting you made. Thx.

Comment: Uploaded the model to Blend-Exchange.
https://blend-exchange.com/b/pmw3o8QK
Hope this gives you a better idea of my issue.

Comment: An embedded illustration here.. a representative screen-grab .. might help folks decide whether they can help before committing to a download? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you see if you display the face orientation, the normals are flipped, you need to recalculate in *Edit* mode (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>):

[image]

Comment: brother i will rig it perfectly give me time , in evening you will get nice rigged model

Comment: Upon fixing the normals, the armature won't move with the mesh. Still appreciate the information tho.

Comment: @Ginsai Your problem is too vague, the armature is not complete, you need to finish it:  join the head to the legs armature, create the arms, spine and so on, as for the mesh, join the legs and the head to the body, keep the cape apart for the moment, recalculate the normals, parent With Automatic Weights

Comment: brother i wish this could be the perfect platform to cuss blender software developer but unfortunately i can not

Comment: i have to take a day on it

Comment: Why do you want to cuss them?

Comment: some mistakes developed like first i cleared objects origin mistakes i aligned objects in center also rotation of upper body was weird which was the user mistake no problem later i cleared after skinning weight paint stuff later suddenly left leg mesh was not moving with bone clearly right one was fine i checked everything but it was not solved , it was an unknown error , also in beginning i symmetrized meshes + separated sheath , sword , pouches on waist and leg .